# "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" java envirenment primefaces

Tags: jquery, html, dom, primefaces, java-ee-6

Well , this my code , i'm trying to add to the enter button a tab behavior( when i click on enter , the next input will focus).

When i press the enter key , an Uncaught RangeError appears.
I tried everything , but nothing changed.

Environment : JavaEE( primefaces ). jquery.

```
function ifNotTextPass(selector) {
    if (selector.next().is('input[type="text"]')) {
        alert('yes');
        selector.next().focus();
    } else {
        if (selector.next() !== null) {
            ifNotTextPass(selector.next());
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="text"]').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            ifNotTextPass($(this));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Nope, Recursion loop executes continuosly so that error occurs. please stop the loop or break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is : an infinite call to the function , it's like and infinite loop.

i ve changed the whole code structure. And i ve arrived to the solution without getting any error.

This code will give the same behavior of the tab button to the enter button. plus it will focus just on text and textareas.

```
$(document).on('keydown', 'input[type="text"],textarea', function(e) {
            var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;

           if(key === 13) {
               e.preventDefault();
               $(this).focus();
               var inputs = $(this).parents('body').find(':input[type="text"]:enabled:visible:not("disabled"),textarea');

                inputs.eq( inputs.index(this)+ 1 ).focus();
                inputs.eq( inputs.index(this)+ 1 ).click();  

                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery selector will never return null, so you have recursion until the stack overflows. Try this instead:

```
if (selector.next().length) {
```

Comment: well, even if i take it off , it shows the same problem

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that demonstrates the issue?